# Read txt from Panda groupby to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

Ok, so I wrote a txt with a pd.groupby dataframe. Now i need to open it.

What I got so far is:

```
f = open('C:/MDH.txt', 'r')
reg = f.read()
rege = np.asarray(reg)
```

but that just gives me a long line with \n where the row ended in the original array, but with no delimitation for the 422472 elements. As an example a part:

```
array('4.498000000000000000e+03 5.866666666666667140e+00 1.989999999999999858e+01 6.763333333333333997e+01 3.600000000000000000e+01 0.000000000000000000e+00 -7.165617522142724738e+00 2.800000000000000000e+01 4.000000000000000000e+00 3.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00\n4.495000000000000000e+03 5.799999999999999822e+00
```

What i need is to recover this to an array of 12 columns by 35.206 rows, for the 422472 elements in the txt.

Also, i need to know how to convert in python from 1.989999999999999858e+01 to 19.89.

I dont need the index of the original groupby, just the columns by rows.

Comment: How di you save the data frame? As a csv? Did you save a particular column? Can you please provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I had a dataframe MDH. The i used groupby :
>MDH = MDH.groupby(['mes','dia','hora']).mean(). Then I created the txt with: >np.savetxt('MDH.txt',MDH)

Comment: Oh, okay. Then `np.loadtxt` will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) which automatically reads your file and parses its contents.

First, I create some dummy data and save it:

```
In [627]: x = np.random.randn(35206, 12)

In [629]: np.savetxt('MDH.txt', x)
```

Next, I can load it using `np.loadtxt`:

```
In [630]: y = np.loadtxt('C:/MDH.txt')

In [631]: y.shape
Out[631]: (35206, 12)

In [632]: y.dtype
Out[632]: dtype('float64')
```

Comment: @AdolfoDonoso Do consider accepting this answer if it helped. Thank you :)